org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException on GCP
i'm getting below exception on environment however my service is working fine on local.

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'portfolioCommonServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'portfolioFolderDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'portfolioFolderDaoImpl': Bean with name 'portfolioFolderDaoImpl' has been injected into other beans [portfolioServiceImpl] in its raw version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped. This means that said other beans do not use the final version of the bean. This is often the result of over-eager type matching - consider using 'getBeanNamesForType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off, for example.

tried applying @Lazy on portfolioFolderDao but it is still same .

There are many ways to deal with this problem. But, here are some workarounds that you could try to solve this issue with circular dependency:

I understand that you’ve applied @Lazy to your configuration classes. For reference, we need to identify which @Autowired property is the reason for circular dependency and to break the application.

@Autowired 
private SampleService sampleService;

Once identified, use @Lazy on top of the @Autowired annotation.
@Lazy
@Autowired
private SampleService sampleService;


Make sure that application is placed in the same directory as the scanned package. Link:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.22.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html#using-boot-locating-the-main-class
package com.example.parent.customer 

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.example.parent"}) 
public class SpringBootApp { 
//main method 
}



Ensure that you use the supported dependency version as there are classes, methods and properties that were deprecated in Spring boot 2.4. You can find it here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.6-Release-Notes#circular-references-prohibited-by-default

Review this article where it covers the common cause and its solutions for the exception of BeanCreationException in Spring Boot. Link: https://www.javaguides.net/2023/08/beancreationexception-in-spring-boot.html

You can try breaking the circular reference by introducing a third bean or by reconfiguring your beans to avoid the circular reference. Link: https://www.springcloud.io/post/2022-08/async-circular-dependency/#gsc.tab=0

I have found this article (https://www.baeldung.com/circular-dependencies-in-spring) that talks about helping solving circular dependency in Spring using Setter/Field Injection which Spring creates Beans, but the dependencies are not injected until they are needed and @PostConstruct which is another way to break the cycle by injecting a dependency using @Autowired on one of the beans and then using a method annotated with @PostConstruct to set the other dependency.


Using Setter/Field Injection
@Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    @Bean
    public CircularDependencyA getCircularDependencyA() {
        return new CircularDependencyA();
    }

    @Bean
    public CircularDependencyB getCircularDependencyB() {
        return new CircularDependencyB();
    }

    @Test
    public void givenCircularDependency_whenSetterInjection_thenItWorks() {
        CircularDependencyA circA = context.getBean(CircularDependencyA.class);

        Assert.assertEquals("Hi!", circA.getCircB().getMessage());
   }
}

Using @PostConstruct
@Autowired
    private CircularDependencyB circB;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        circB.setCircA(this);

Also, check out these answers that could help resolve your issue with circular reference:

Spring Framework uses a special logic for resolving these kinds of circular dependencies

Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Requested bean is currently in creation

Injection of autowired dependencies failed


If none of these workarounds fix your issue, please let me know and share your configuration classes.
